# Запрос для поиска по части слова

Tags: java, postgresql, servlet

Всем привет, такой вопросик, есть сервлет в нем такой вот запрос для поиска:

`String query = "select * from clippersql.skisql where kiz='" + kiz + "'";`

Проблема в том что поиск происходит только по полному названию поля `kiz`, как сделать так что-бы искало допустим по одной букве или части поля `kiz`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть два решения - оператор [LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) и [полнотекстовый поиск](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/textsearch.html).

Первый вариант простой. Чтобы найти все записи, в которых поле `kiz` начинается с данных в переменной `kiz`:

```
String query = "select * from clippersql.skisql where kiz like '" + kiz + "%'";
```

Настройка второго - нетривиальная задача, описание которой выходит за рамки формата Stackoverflow.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло, буду знать

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Есть возможность ещё использовать поиск на основе триграмм.
[pg_trgm](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/pgtrgm)

```
-- создание индекса
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON words USING gist (word gist_trgm_ops);
-- пример самого поиска        
SELECT word, similarity(word, 'собака') AS sml FROM words 
      WHERE word % 'собака' 
      ORDER BY sml DESC, word;

select word from words order by w <-> 'risource' limit 5;

-- pg_trgm supports indexing of regular-expression searches 
select w from words where w ~ '^r.*sour.*e$';
```

создание такого индекса оптимизирует поиск по LIKE.
то есть если вы в приложении используете

```
where kiz like '%текст%'
```

то, используется индекс с триграммами для ускорения такого поиска.